# Translate/Map SVG image element to DOM/XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, svg, web-inspector

I am trying to translate SVG image elements to it's xml text line. In other words if there is a square at (0,0), I want to find it's corresponding xml line in the SVG text file.

Now, I know that I can search svg xml file for these co-ordinates and find it. But the difficulty is with **transform and clipping**. These might mean the location of an element might be different in svg xml and real svg image.

In short what I want to do is similar to **web-inspector(safari) functions**. But I want to implement it myself. I found several links on how to write dom inspectors. But there require SVG to have onmouseclick or onmousehover functions in each element. **What I want to do is, write a program that can to take any random svg, where once an element is selected, I can get its corresponding xml line.**

I hope someone can guide me on how to go about this.

Comment: xml line from what markup ? The one you originally wrote ? It doesn't exist anymore from the page. The one you would get from serializing the whole document at this time ? The one you would get by serializing only the svg node at this time ?

Comment: I refer to XML line of the SVG image itself. I want the to get the relevant XML line of the SVG element, when I select that SVG element in the svg image itself. Similar to what happens with web inspector in safari. Where it finds for you the <polygon ....> from svgs' xml when you click on a polygon in svg image.

Comment: call document.elementFromPoint, then serialise the element you get from that using XMLSerializer

Comment: Unfortunately I have been working on python for a long time and I'm new to javascript. Honestly I have no idea about XML seralizing. I will read about it. Thank you. It will be very helpful if you can suggest any guides on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Robert Longson. I got the answer from your help.

I used 'elementFromPoint()' function as he suggested. Assuming the program knows already which cordinates(100,60) it wants to check; by calling elemenfrompoint() at window.onload() I got the answer as follows.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    cord_element = document.elementFromPoint(100,60);
    alert("element is :"+cord_element.id);
}
```